# Spring JPA Hibernate Vs Spring Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa-2.0

Performance point of view, which one should be the better option whether **Spring JPA Hibernate** or **Spring Hibernate** ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not expect any relevant Perfomance Difference between Hibernate JPA and classic Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should worry about it. Reasonably it is as Ralph expressed it. Instead go ahead and use JPA because your code will be vendor independent. Or go for Hibernate if you have a reason for it, (maybe better documented or something).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this link helps for performance report you are looking at

http://www.jpab.org/All/All/All.html.